# How to find an alphabet and extract the alphabet and the number tagged along with it in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a new column in the data frame that will search for the alphabet in a column. Based on it, it will then search for the next number and copy the alphabet and number into newly extracted column. Example:

| Month | Sem_Year |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-04-01 | H1 2020 |
| 2020-05-01 | 2020 H1 |
| 2020-06-01 | H1 2020 |
| 2020-07-01 | H2 2020 |
| 2020-08-01 | H2 2020 |
| 2020-09-01 | 2020 H2 |
| 2020-10-01 | 2020 H2 |
| 2020-11-01 | H2 2020 |
| 2020-12-01 | H2 2020 |
| 2021-01-01 | H1 2021 |
| 2021-02-01 | H1 2021 |

Now I want to search for the alphabet H in the second column and extract the alphabet and number tagged along with it. Example:

| Month | Sem_Year | Sem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04-01 | H1 2020 | H1 |
| 2020-05-01 | 2020 H1 | H1 |
| 2020-06-01 | H1 2020 | H1 |
| 2020-07-01 | H2 2020 | H2 |
| 2020-08-01 | H2 2020 | H2 |
| 2020-09-01 | 2020 H2 | H2 |
| 2020-10-01 | 2020 H2 | H2 |
| 2020-11-01 | H2 2020 | H2 |
| 2020-12-01 | H2 2020 | H2 |
| 2021-01-01 | H1 2021 | H1 |
| 2021-02-01 | H1 2021 | H1 |

Comment: Can you just split it and take the first item? Have you asked a question other than can someone do this for me?

Comment: Yup, I have used a similar approach. But there are a few instances where the alphabet is not the first character. Example 2nd row, 6th and 7th row. So, splitting is resulting in an incorrect result.
I apologize if you felt so. But I don't have that much experience with python and am starting to gain my understanding/

Comment: Modified answer to meet this requirement given below and does not depend on split()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the varied formats you have defined you need to use a Regex expression. Note that `H\d` means H followed by a digit. This regex could be modified for other requirements.

```
df['Sem'] = df['Sem_year'].str.extract("(H\d)")
```

Comment: Yup this works only if the location of "H" is fixed i.e. either at the start or end. I have edited the sample data frame. Can you please check and help me?

Comment: Answer modified to meet the newly stated requirement.

Comment: Can you also help me with extracting year like 2021 in a separate column using similar query please?

Comment: Currently, I am writing 
df['Year'] = df['Time Grain'].str.extract("(20\d\d)") similar to yours.

Comment: If your data is in DateTime format and not a string then you need to use a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.insert() to add a new column. For extracting the alphabet, loop through the values (column_value) in the second column and use "value_for_new_column=column_value.split(' ')[0]"